# Saving screenshot of <iframe> object in notebook?

Tags: google-chrome, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm inserting `<iframe ...>` objects that reference remote website and give me an interactive visualization in notebook in Chrome (from [Simple way to visualize a TensorFlow graph in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189119/simple-way-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-in-jupyter/38192374#38192374)) . The downside of this is that when I close the notebook, and then open it again, all the visualizations are replaced with empty whitespace.

I suspect showing it requires re-executing javascript code in the `iframe`.

Another downside is that when hosting this notebook (ie, github), all such cells are empty, so a static image approach is more portable than re-executing javascript.

Can someone see a way to save screenshots of these cells and embedding them into notebook? Maybe something like `camera_ready(14)` which will embed static screenshot of visualization from output cell 14.

Answer (score 2):

[PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) can help you with screen capture. While your notebook is running, PhantomJS browser will open it and make a screenshot of a specified output cell:

JS file for PhantomJS:

```
// address of the notebook
var address = "http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Untitled.ipynb";
// auth token from Jupyter console
var authToken = "af6bc1d90688bb6c26aeb206b8690e4855d27ef8d265b1bc";
// cell number with a widget output
var cellNumber = 10;

// this function is used to verify that a page is fully loaded
// source: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/waitfor.js
function waitFor(testFx, onReady, timeOutMillis) {
    var maxtimeOutMillis = timeOutMillis ? timeOutMillis : 3000,
        start = new Date().getTime(),
        condition = false,
        interval = setInterval(function() {
            if ( (new Date().getTime() - start < maxtimeOutMillis) && !condition ) {
                // If not time-out yet and condition not yet fulfilled
                condition = (typeof(testFx) === "string" ? eval(testFx) : testFx());
            } else {
                if(!condition) {
                    // If condition still not fulfilled (timeout but condition is 'false')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' timeout");
                    phantom.exit(1);
                } else {
                    // Condition fulfilled (timeout and/or condition is 'true')
                    console.log("'waitFor()' finished in " + (new Date().getTime() - start) + "ms.");
                    typeof(onReady) === "string" ? eval(onReady) : onReady();
                    clearInterval(interval); //< Stop this interval
                }
            }
        }, 250); //< repeat check every 250ms
};

// log in to a notebook using a token
function logIn() {
    console.log("Logging in");
    page.evaluate(function(token) {
        document.forms[0].password.value = token;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }, authToken);
}

// wait for a notebook to fully load, find the
// needed output cell and save it as a PNG file
function saveAsPNG() {
    console.log("Saving PNG")
    // Wait for 'notebook-container' to be visible
    waitFor(function() {
        // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible
        return page.evaluate(function() {
            return $("#notebook-container").is(":visible");
        });
    }, function() {
        console.log("The notebook-container element should be visible now.");
        var clipRect = page.evaluate(function(cell){
            // we are selecting only the output cell
            var searchStr = 'div.input_prompt:contains("[' + cell + ']:")';
            var parentCell = $(searchStr).parents('div.cell')[0];
            // get only the data div
            var outputSubarea = $(parentCell).find('div.output_subarea')[0];
            // get the coordinates of the data div
            return outputSubarea.getBoundingClientRect()
        }, cellNumber);

        page.clipRect = {
            top:    clipRect.top,
            left:   clipRect.left,
            width:  clipRect.width,
            height: clipRect.height
          };
       page.render('example.png');
       phantom.exit();
    });
}

var page = require('webpage').create();
// it seems, viewportSize should fully cover the
// the rendered div position, or nothing will be saved.
page.viewportSize = { width: 5000, height: 5000 };

page.open(address, function (status) {
    // Check for page load success
    if (status !== "success") {
        console.log("Unable to open a page");
    } else {
        // Wait for 'password_input' to be visible
        waitFor(function() {
            // Check in the page if a specific element is now visible
            return page.evaluate(function() {
                return $("#password_input").is(":visible");
            });
        }, function() {
           console.log("The password_input element should be visible now.");
           logIn();
           saveAsPNG();
        });
    }
});
```

Specify the address of your notebook, auth token and cell number in the script and run it with phantomjs:

`phantomjs script.js`

Comment: The challenge here is that it's not just a static external webpage showed in output, but a javascript widget which has been interacted with in the notebook. So I want to save the same thing I'm seeing in the notebook (the widget is http://stackoverflow.com/q/39840323/419116 )

Comment: PhantomJS is a headless web browser capable of evaluating JS. How do you pass your data to the widget in iframe? Do you use URL parameters? If so, use the same URL to open it in PhantomJS and save the screenshot.

Comment: I physically interact with it using my mouse, so there are no parameters sent over to the server. (it's basically a javascript graph visualizer that lets you customize a view interactively)

Comment: Ok, then we will make a screenshot from the address of your notebook. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov, have you checked the solution? Does it work for you?

Comment: That was actually due to mispelling of URL, after fixing it I now have infinite stream of "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'outputResult.getBoundingClientRect')" errors. I tried it on various cells, not just the ones with javascript widget

Comment: It looks like the output cell was not found. Could you use this debug version of the script: http://pastebin.com/pEiPC2sN and show me it's output?

Comment: Could you also export a notebook as pdf or make a screenshot of the area with a cell with iframe on which it fails? And what version of Jupyter Notebook are you using? For me it works nicely on version 4.3.1. When an output cell with the specified number exists in a notebook, the screenshot is always created.

Comment: Here's the notebook with error message and script I used (I tried your script on first cell of same notebook ) -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/phantomjs-tryout.ipynb

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov, I fixed the issue. Please use updated code from the answer. The problem was that the logic relied on 'Out[```num```]' text when searching for output cell and didn't handle cells without a prompt. Now it should work for any cell.

Comment: Hm, it generates me this image -- https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/example.png . I've updated notebook with screenshot of what I actually see https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/phantomjs-tryout.ipynb . Works on other cells though.

Comment: Well, the question is how the widget inserts its elements. I need to look at the DOM of the page. If you are using Chrome, could you right click on the widget -> Inspect, then navigate to the root ```div class="cell"``` select it and copy (http://imgur.com/a/x6lZB). I need to look at the resulting listing.

Comment: Here's a paste of the whole output cell with the widget -- http://pastebin.com/vurHCk0G

Comment: Unfortunately, iframe with a graph visualization is always rendered blank. I have no idea why. Tried different approaches with no luck.

Comment: I will try to investigate further, as for some reason it does not work specifically with that iframe. If you embed an iframe from YouTube for example it's rendered successfuly. Will let you know if I find a solution.