# Is there a way to visualize TensorBoard logs in Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm able to display the tf graph itself in Jupyter using code from here:

[Simple way to visualize a TensorFlow graph in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189119/simple-way-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-in-jupyter/38192374#38192374)

But I'm interested in more full featured tensorboard functionality, like visualizing training progress. I'm running in Azure Notebooks, where I'm not able to run a tensorboard server.