# Simple way to visualize TensorFlow Scalars in Jupyter?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I would like to be able to embed the TensorBoard plots of scalar summaries in a Jupyter notebook. That is something equivalent to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189119/simple-way-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-in-jupyter), but for the scalar summaries.

How would I go about this?