# can't display tensorboard in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter, tensorboard

I am using tensorflow on jupyter notebook. I have no problems using tensorflow, but when I try to display tensorboard using the "show_graph" function (it was referenced here: [Simple way to visualize a TensorFlow graph in Jupyter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38189119/simple-way-to-visualize-a-tensorflow-graph-in-jupyter)), all it showed is a blank space. My classmates who ran the same code had no problem opening the tensorboard.

My system is Win 10. I am new to jupyter notebook and tensorflow so I don't know what to do for troubleshooting.

Comment: No errors have occur. It is just a blank where it's supposed to show the graph.